# Call Code Behind Function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-behind

I want to call or fire code behind function from javascript. I use this code :

```
var item = <% fillHistoryGrid() %> ;
```

but when i write like this, i get error :

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

Note : my code behind function starts : Public Sub ....

What should i do ?

Comment: Let's see who makes sense out of this..

Comment: I think what he is looking for is something called AJAX. if you google AJAX + VB.NET, you will find some pretty nifty tutorials. It won't be easy, though

Answer (score 0):

What is the templating engine you are using (ASP, JSP, some JavaScript one)? That should support such requirements, most likely the syntax will look like <%= %>

Comment: I use VB.NET.. i used <%= %>, <%# %> but i couldn't get result.

Comment: Do you get any error or it just simply does not work? I am not a VB.NET developer, I can only guess beyond this point... I suspect the code you are calling is not visible (include?).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using c#/vb.net and calling code-behind function in javascript in asp.net
your code behind function must be static (shared if vb.net)

```
public static void funname()
{
}
```

and call funname in javascript
by using

```
PageMethods.funname()
```

'